# Calling DataTable using Function and get the TD data when clicked, but receiving an error of "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

i'm having trouble on getting the data of `<td>` on a table but receiving this error "**Cannot read property '0' of undefined**" .

what i wanted is, when i click the `<tr>` of the table it suppose to get the `<td>` data.

This code is working fine and get the result.

```
  var my_table= jQuery('#my_table').DataTable({
         "lengthChange": false,
         "autoWidth": false,
         "searching": true,
         "ordering": false,
         "processing":true,
         "serverSide":true,
         "order":[],
         "ajax":{
           url:"admin-ajax.php",
           data:{action:"table_json"},
           type:"POST"
         },
         "columnDefs":[
           {
             "targets":[0],
             "orderable":false,
           },
         ],
  });
jQuery('#my_table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
     var data = my_table.row( this ).data() ;
     console.log(data[0]);
} );
```

but when i wrap this on a function example:

```
function call_thisTable(ParameterA,ParameterB){
 var my_table= jQuery('#my_table').DataTable({
             "lengthChange": false,
             "autoWidth": false,
             "searching": true,
             "ordering": false,
             "processing":true,
             "serverSide":true,
             "order":[],
             "ajax":{
               url:"admin-ajax.php",
               data:{action:"table_json"},
               type:"POST"
             },
             "columnDefs":[
               {
                 "targets":[0],
                 "orderable":false,
               },
             ],
      });
    jQuery('#my_table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
         var data = my_table.row( this ).data() ;
         console.log(data[0]);
    } );
}
```

Then everytime i click a "button" i will destroy the table first to reinitiate the content and call this function `call_thisTable(A,B)`.

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".click_button",function(){
  var A = jQuery(this).attr("data-a");
  var B = jQuery(this).attr("data-b");

  $('#my_table').DataTable().destroy();
  call_thisTable(A,B);
});
```

On my first call of `call_thisTable(A,B);`, you will get the data you want, but on the second,third and so on, you will get the "**Cannot read property '0' of undefined**" error. 
[image]

Comment: There's something wrong when you're re-creating the table. The error is specific to line in your columnDefs, "targets":[0],

Comment: can you explain it to me sir  @Afdusko ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Afdufsko,
To fix this issue.  i rolled out the datatable initialization outside of the function.

```
var my_table= jQuery('#my_table').DataTable({
             "lengthChange": false,
             "autoWidth": false,
             "searching": true,
             "ordering": false,
             "processing":true,
             "serverSide":true,
             "order":[],
             "ajax":{
               url:"admin-ajax.php",
               data:{action:"table_json"},
               type:"POST"
             },
             "columnDefs":[
               {
                 "targets":[0],
                 "orderable":false,
               },
             ],
      });
function call_thisTable(my_table,ParameterA,ParameterB){
    jQuery('#my_table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
         var data = my_table.row( this ).data() ;
         console.log(data[0]); 
         //do some ajax here
    } );
}
```

Then instead of destroying the datatable to initiate new contents, i used `ajax.reload()`.

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".click_button",function(){
  var A = jQuery(this).attr("data-a");
  var B = jQuery(this).attr("data-b");

  $('#my_table').ajax.reload();
  call_thisTable(my_table,A,B);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with this line of code.

```
    $('#my_table').DataTable().destroy();
```

You're initializing a datatable and destroying it at the same time. Try getting rid of

```
    DataTable()
```

in that line.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).destroy is not a function

Comment: i fix my issue thank you for pointing this part, instead of using `destoy()` i use `ajax.reload()`